# Setting different layout for different screens

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, screen, multiscreen

n my application, I want to set different font size and paddings for different mobile devices. I use this method explain in Android documentation.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

i use galaxy s2 and htc one for the testing ,
it seems no matter what folder i create it allways use the xml from the res/layout/

i added this in manifest

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

how can i make sure the galaxy and htc one will use different xml ? instead the current situation that they both use the default layout .

Comment: Galaxy S2 has normal sized screen that is why it takes the layout from /res/layout/

Comment: and htc one takes also from there ?

Comment: htc one has an xxhdpi resolution. I guess you have to prepare an xxlarge folder? or try with xxhdpi.

Comment: see this [table of ressource qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) and pick the ones you need

Answer (score 1):

Galaxy S2 uses folder :

```
layout-normal-hdpi
```

HTC One uses folder :

```
layout-normal-xxhdpi
```

manifest :

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will paste this code in your mainfest file

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 
   />

<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />        
</compatible-screens>
```

And then delete the layout file in res folder because it will automatically take the default screen for all..So

An then you can specify the values for all screen size like this...

```
      res/values-small/my_layoutvalues.xml       // layout for small screen size
      res/values-large/my_layoutvalues.xml       // layout for large screen size
      res/values-xlarge/my_layoutvalues.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
      res/values-xlarge-land/my_layoutvalues.xml //layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

that's all if you need any clarification comment...

Comment: for like this errors you can mention SW values in your res folder...like layout-sw420dp,layout-sw720dp,layout-sw600dp,etc

Comment: You can classify the values for this problem but Android is only supporting the 4,4.7,7,10 inches screen only if you want design other then this screen you go with dynamic adjustments only...

Answer (score 0):

for phones upto 5'1" screen

```
use layout folder only
Note: use linear layout as parent layout and use weights as weight divide each screen 
in equal parts
```

for 7" tablet

```
layout-sw600dp-port //for portrait mode
layout-sw600dp-land //for landscape mode
```

for 10" tablet

```
layout-sw720dp-port //for portrait mode
layout-sw720dp-land //for landscape mode
```